# laravel 5 routing in working app folder other than the examples that use the default 127.0.0.1 root

Tags: php, html, laravel

am trying to understand the laravel 5 routing bt its giving me headache.am using vagrant.in my `routes.php` i have the following:

```
  Route::get('/about','RoutingController@index');
    Route::controllers ( [ 
        'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
        'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController' 
    ] );
```

then in my controller I have

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RoutingController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        return 'This is all about Asiago !';
    }
}
```

my app is in `http://192.168.33.10/Php-Projects/laravel`
when i navigate to `http://192.168.33.10/Php-Projects/laravel/public/about` path. `404 error` appears.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a vhost in Apache that points to the public directory...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName laravelproject.dev
    DocumentRoot /path/to/laravel/public/folder
</VirtualHost>
```

Point `laravelproject.dev` to `192.168.33.10` in your hosts file.

Then browse to `http://laravelproject.dev/about`

Comment: can't it work using just this path that I have at the moment ?

Comment: It won't recognise the path... /about != /Php-Projects/laravel/public/about

Comment: I went on looking for a solution in the past 2 moths including laravel cookbook but no answer so far. is there anyone who can take me through this please my code the default "/" URL is working but http://www.whendocapp.com/about gives 404 error

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution
1. make `vhost` in wamp
2. in wamp go to tray icon `apache>apache modules`  scroll and check the `rewrite_module`